# Url.Action doesn't give me the correct path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my view I have the following code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
</script>
```

The problem it emits simply...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '/';
</script>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, the default routing configuration is configured to use the Home controller and the Index action by default.

See the `RegisterRoutes` method in your `HttpApplication` type:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // parameter defaults
);
```

If you link to a parameter value which is configured as a default, MVC will avoid rendering it in the output, as it isn't required.

Answer (score 2):

It is not wrong. That's because `Index` and `Home` are the default (I think so if you just started), so MVC knows automatically that no URL is needed.

If you call `/Home/Index` it's the same as you call `/`.
You can see your default routes in your global.asax under `RegisterRoutes`.